# Get Hostname in WCF on IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

Based on below pic, there may be several WebSite on IIS with several services,

[image]

So the only thing which I have separate them from together is `Hostname` , in the other site sibling services may call together so I have decided to change `hostname` if they are not on localhost so in service I tried something like this:

```
HostName = OperationContext.Current.Channel.LocalAddress.Uri.Host.ToString();
```

and in service when I am calling another service by it's proxy I `Rehome`

```
 public void ReHome(string hostName)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hostName))
        {
            if (this.Endpoint.Address.Uri.DnsSafeHost.ToLower().Equals("localhost"))
            {
                string newAddress = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}/{3}", Endpoint.Address.Uri.Scheme
                    , hostName, string.IsNullOrEmpty(Endpoint.Address.Uri.Port.ToString()) ? string.Empty : ":" + Endpoint.Address.Uri.Port.ToString()
                    , Endpoint.Address.Uri.AbsolutePath);
                this.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(newAddress);
            }
        }
    }
```

call example in a service:

```
 using (var hisProxy = new HISIntegrationClient("hisIntegrationEndPoint", Internals.SYSTEM))
        {
            hisProxy.ReHome(HostName);
            ....
        }
```

so is `OperationContext.Current.Channel.LocalAddress.Uri.Host` give me what I want that mentioned in above pic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the current base address of server(hostname and port) using following code snippet

```
var baseAddress = OperationContext.Current.Host.BaseAddresses[0].Authority;
```

Comment: Let me check it, what is the difference between them ?

Comment: Nop I facing some problem when set hostname in IIS, service's operation won't be accessed, I will tell the feed back...

Comment: It worked, It gave me Hostname but my code `OperationContext.Current.Channel.LocalAddress.Uri.Host.ToString()` also give me Hostname truly.

Comment: Of course I'll accepted but as you have seen my question, what is the differences between your code and mine, they both are giving me Hostname truly, if your code is better please add more explain, thanks.

Comment: @Aria Sure I will add :)