# Get hostname in ASP.Net on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Based on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47968440/get-hostname-in-wcf-on-iis)

I am going to get the hostname in `Application_Start` so I have done it before something like:

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Hostname)) 
        Hostname = Dns.GetHostName();
```

Based on this screenshot:

[image]

But it returns `skyweb` - but I want to get `RND1`.

The other solution to get hostname is `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;` but as you know I don't want get in through the pages event it is better be initiated at first go...

So what is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit1:**

If you take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47968440/get-hostname-in-wcf-on-iis) you will see what I am looking for which pointed in picture, meanwhile I mentioned in this screenshot again:

[image]

I can't set this in configuration, It may be set while installing process or be set by admin of server manually.

I am looking for hostname while be set in adding new website.

Comment: Why don't you just have a setting in your configuration (such as appsettings) where you specify this yourself? Trying to automatically determine it based on DNS lookups or checking the bindings is going to be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: RND1 and RND2 are not host names.  They're site names.  DNS and/or URL hostnames are not necessarily the same as the machine name either.  All of those are separate things, so it's not clear what you're really asking for.

Comment: Please see the update section.

Comment: RND1 and RND2 are sitename but I also set the hostname same, anyway there should be a way to get hostname from binding or something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we add hostname and binding the `applicationHost.config` file get changed which located at `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config` so per site it get some change like `binding`,`apppool` and etc, for me I see the binding for `RND1` is something like :

```
<site name="RND1" id="3">
  <bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:RND1" />
    <binding protocol="net.pipe" bindingInformation="RND1" />
    <binding protocol="net.tcp" bindingInformation="2042:RND1" />
    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:RND1" sslFlags="0" />
    <binding protocol="net.msmq" bindingInformation="RND1" />
   </bindings>
</site>
```

So we can get that `applicationhost` file and manipulate it but with some search  I crossed to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2011/01/21/get-iis-bindings-at-runtime-without-being-an-administrator/) which give some helpful info to get IIS binding at run time.

with little changes of codes I implemented it like below to get hostname:

```
 private static string GetHostname()
    {
        // Get the Site name 
        string siteName = HostingEnvironment.SiteName; 
        // Get the sites section from the AppPool.config
        Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationSection sitesSection =
            Microsoft.Web.Administration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection(null, null,
                "system.applicationHost/sites");
        foreach (Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement site in sitesSection.GetCollection())
        {
            // Find the right Site
            if (string.Equals((string)site["name"], siteName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            { 
                // For each binding see if they are http based and return the port and protocol
                foreach (Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement binding in site.GetCollection("bindings"))
                {
                    var bindingInfo = (string)binding["bindingInformation"]; 
                    return bindingInfo.Split(':')[2]; 
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and using it in `application_start` like:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Hostname))
            Hostname = GetHostname();
    }
```

Comment: This will likely work under the debugger, but does this work from *within* the application, when running under IIS?  I don't think the default IIS application identity has access to these objects.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your application has access to the IIS configuration data (they usually don't), the host name in the box you're referring to can only be accessed as part of the URL *during* a request.  One of the reasons for this is that there can be any number of bindings for a site, and they can even have wildcards.  I have previously attempted to access the site binding configuration from the application itself, but it appears that applications do not have rights to read their own configuration.  I'm not sure why Microsoft chose to make that restriction, and there may be a good reason for it, but I'm not aware of what it is.

Comment: Yes there may be any number of binding for a site, but if I can get the Hostname from Http binding the prob resolved for me, but in `app_start`

Comment: As I said, this information is not accessible from the application itself (at least it was when I tried to get it a few years back on IIS 7).

Comment: I ended up writing an installation script that queried the information from IIS during installation (you have access then) and put it into the web.config in a setting, and some years later I abandoned that in favor of a different approach that computed the value for each request based on the URL used to access the application.